# Calculating the number of days a range of dates c#

Tags: c#, ienumerable

**Updated**

I have a list of travels in the database with a various start and end dates, i would like to calculate the sum number of days that each travel has that corresponds with the defined range.

For example:

I want to query the number of days for the trip to Boston in the range following range:

RangeEnd is 27. Nov. 2017 
RangeStart is 1. Nov. 2017

Here is my updated code:

```
 var travel = new List<Travel>
 {
     new Travel("Egypt", new DateTime(2017, 8, 4), new DateTime(2017, 8, 24) ),
     new Travel("Spain", new DateTime(2017, 11, 1), new DateTime(2017, 12, 10) ),
     new Travel("Detroit", new DateTime(2017,9, 15), new DateTime(2017, 12, 20) ),
     new Travel("Boston", new DateTime(2017,10, 15), new DateTime(2017, 11, 20) ),

 };
 var rangeStart = new DateTime(2017, 11, 1);
 var rangeEnd = new DateTime(2017, 11, 27);
 var Trip = travel.Where(t => t.Country=="Boston");
 var sumOfDays= Trip.Sum(t => ????);
```

The expected result for this case is 20 days.
Can anyone help?

Comment: So does `travel12TimesCount` contain the right number? If so, why not?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. What do you **_expect_** the output to be, and what are you getting?

Comment: `Sum(s => m.EndOfMonth` what is that `m`?

Comment: If you create two `DateTime` objects and subtract them, you will get a `TimeSpan`.  You can read the number of days from that object.  You can also get the number of hours (for rounding).

Comment: The expected output from the example is 26 - here you go: https://dotnetfiddle.net/b3LOzn

Comment: @Flydog57 OP is already doing that in their code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Flydog57 for helping me figuring it out. i took your idea of calling another function and it worked with the range.

```
 var travel = new List<Travel>
 {
     new Travel("Egypt", new DateTime(2017, 8, 4), new DateTime(2017, 8, 24) ),
     new Travel("Spain", new DateTime(2017, 11, 1), new DateTime(2017, 12, 10) ),
     new Travel("Detroit", new DateTime(2017,9, 15), new DateTime(2017, 12, 20) ),
     new Travel("Boston", new DateTime(2017,10, 15), new DateTime(2017, 11, 20) ),

 };
 var rangeStart = new DateTime(2017, 11, 1);
 var rangeEnd = new DateTime(2017, 11, 27);

 var Trip= travel.Where(s => s != null && s.City == "Boston");

 var sumOfDays= Trip.Sum(t => GetTravelDaysWithinRange(t.Start,t.End,rangeStart, rangeEnd));
```

And the function that calculates the days is:

```
 public int GetTravelDaysWithinRange( DateTime start, DateTime end, DateTime rangeStart, DateTime rangeEnd)
 {
        int days = 0;
        while (start <= end)
        {
            if (start.Month>= rangeStart.Month && start.Month <= rangeEnd.Month && start.Year >= rangeStart.Year && start.Year <= rangeEnd.Year)
            {
                ++days;
            }
            start = start.AddDays(1);
        }
        return days;
  }
```

And the exact value of 20 was resulted :)))))

Comment: By the way, the correct way to say "thank you" is to upvote any answer you find useful. If one of the answers is the one that you ended up using to get to a solution, you can *accept* it. That way, years from now, when someone googles looking for a solution to a problem similar to yours, they will find answers in a nice sort order.

Comment: For what it's worth, my guess is that if you changed the last line of my function from `return (endInRange - startInRange).Days;` to `return (endInRange - startInRange).Days + 1;`, you'd get the same answer.  And, it's not comparing the bits of a DateTime or iterating in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in 1 line

```
var Trip = travel.Where(t => t.Country == "Boston").Select(x => (x.EndDate - x.StartDate).TotalDays).FirstOrDefault();
```

You need first or default incase there are 0 results or more than 1 recuslt

Comment: That didn't consider the range start and end dates.

Answer (score -2):

How about something like this.  The total I get is 55, which is what I expected:

Class Travel:

```
public class Travel
{
    public Travel(string where, DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        Where = where;
        StartDate = start;
        EndDate = end;
    }
    public string Where { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

and then consuming it:

```
  var travel = new List<Travel>
  {
      new Travel("Egypt", new DateTime(2017, 8, 4), new DateTime(2017, 8, 24) ),
      new Travel("Spain", new DateTime(2017, 9, 1), new DateTime(2017, 10, 1) ),
      new Travel("Detroit", new DateTime(2017,9, 15), new DateTime(2017, 9, 20) ),

  };
  var sumOfTravelDays = travel.Sum(t => (t.EndDate - t.StartDate).Days);
```

What kind of issue are you seeing?

### Update

Add this function to the Travel class (either in the class or as an extension method):

```
 public int GetTravelDaysWithinRange(DateTime rangeStart, DateTime rangeEnd)
 {
     //if everything is outside of the range to be considered, return 0
     if (rangeEnd < StartDate || rangeStart > EndDate)
     {
         return 0;
     }

     //Find the Max of StartDate and rangeStart 
     var startInRange = (rangeStart < StartDate) ? StartDate : rangeStart;
     //And the Min of EndDate and rangeEnd
     var endInRange = (rangeEnd > EndDate) ? EndDate : rangeEnd;
     //and get the number of days in-between (and then add 1 so Mon-Fri is 5 days, not 4)
     return (endInRange - startInRange).Days + 1;
 }
```

Now, when I run a variation of my original code, it does what I think you want:

```
 var travel = new List<Travel>
 {
     new Travel("Egypt", new DateTime(2017, 8, 4), new DateTime(2017, 8, 24) ),
     new Travel("Spain", new DateTime(2017, 11, 1), new DateTime(2017, 12, 10) ),
     new Travel("Detroit", new DateTime(2017,9, 15), new DateTime(2017, 12, 20) ),
     new Travel("Boston", new DateTime(2017,10, 15), new DateTime(2017, 11, 20) ),

 };
 var rangeStart = new DateTime(2017, 11, 1);
 var rangeEnd = new DateTime(2017, 11, 27);
 var sumOfDates = travel.Sum(t => t.GetTravelDaysWithinRange(rangeStart, rangeEnd));
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. The issue is that is not related to the variables:
m.EndOfMonth is 27. Nov. 2017 
m.StartOfMonth is 1. Nov. 2017 
What i'm trying to achive is to get only the number of days that are in this range only.

Comment: @Sam: I've updated my answer.  I think it should meet your needs

Comment: Not really :(
In your example, lets say we want to get the number of days for the trips in Boston in the same date range which is Nobember 1 to 27 2017.
Still I'm not able to do that...

Comment: I'm not following.  I get Nov 1 (since it started on October 10, but you are only consider dates between Nov 1 and Nov 27) to Nov 20.  I subtract the two and get 19 days.  Now, if I travel from Monday to Friday is that 5 days or 4 days - what does your spec say?  My calculation comes up with 4 days (because it's simple subtraction).  If you want 5 days, well, that's a simple off-by-one error and you get to fix that (hint: add one in `GetTravelDaysWithinRange` - you have a debugger and a compiler and should be able to fix it).  Otherwise, this code passed all my tests.

Comment: Oh, wait a minute, you updated your post (with my code, actually).  If you want to extract the trip to Boston and get the days of travel for that particular trip (only in the range Nov1 to Nov27), use this: `var sumOfDates = travel.Where(t=>t.Where == "Boston").Sum(t => t.GetTravelDaysWithinRange(rangeStart, rangeEnd));`.  The Where clause reduces the list to just a single entry, while the Sum clause comes up with the total travel days.  And, there's the same possible off-by-one issue that you get to figure out